# How to display divs in a row responsively

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a site using six divs in two rows like this.

```
  [ ] [ ] [ ]
  [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

And when i make my browser smaller i want to be displayer like this:

```
  [ ] [ ]
  [ ] [ ]
  [ ] [ ]
```

I've tried with float, @media, inline-block and div containers but doesn't work at all, because it will display like this:

```
  [ ] [ ]
    [ ] 
  [ ] [ ]
    [ ]
```

Please guys, tell me how to resolve because I've tried so many methods but none worked.
Thank you for help.

Comment: If you're able to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), it has a built-in grid system which is pretty easy to use.

Comment: I'd recommend [using flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key element you're looking for is

```
display: inline-block;
```

for your div. 
You can give flexible widths to your element so they fit in your outer div.

Look here and try out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/01ntLun5/

Regards!

Comment: This jsfiddle is definitely the best start to what he wants. Upvoted.

Comment: I've tried it, but didnt work, and I dont know why...

Comment: can you show your code here? so we can try to find the error

Comment: i added comments to the fiddle, so you can understand what the things do exactly. http://jsfiddle.net/01ntLun5/1/
take care: the last line is the one that ensures your boxes flip and rearrange. the "flex" attribute is new in css3 and very good as well. you can google it and try it as well in a fiddle :)

Comment: using stuff like bootstrap is in general not a too bad idea! :) but sometimes we have to do our stuff our own way - so i hope the solution helped!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no pure CSS way to do that. I use jQuery to recalculate width of elements when the window is resizing. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<ul class="column">
  <li>
    <div class="block">
    <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.column{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.column li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px; /* column width by default */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: inline;
}
.block {
  height: 355px;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-right: 10px; /* cell spacing */
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e3e1d5;
}
.block h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
.block img {
  width: 89%; /* -1% for fixing bug in IE6 */
  padding: 5%;
  background:#fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* fix for IE 6/7 */
}
```

jQuery:

```
function smartColumns() {

  $("ul.column").css({ 'width' : "100%"});

  var colWrap = $("ul.column").width(); //get row width
  var colNum = Math.floor(colWrap / 200); //define how much 200px columns this row can contain
  var colFixed = Math.floor(colWrap / colNum); //define max possible column width for this row

  $("ul.column").css({ 'width' : colWrap}); //setting exact width in px insted of "100%" can prevent various bugs in different browsers
  $("ul.column li").css({ 'width' : colFixed}); //set column width

}

smartColumns(); //call function after page has loaded

$(window).resize(function () { //call function after window has resized
  smartColumns();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Bootstrap for your requirements.Here i post the link for the bootstrap gridSystem if you are comfortable with that i suggest you to use that

[visit this site](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Thanks